# Query through multiple associations active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :allocations, class_name: 'Project', inverse_of: :user
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :allocations
end
```

I want to find those users who have no allocation and also whose `start_date` for allocation is less than today.

I need to find it from a collection of `Role` objects. I am trying to define a scope for the same. How can I combine both the conditions together in a single active record query?

Right now I'm doing it separately.

To find users with no allocations, I've tried the following:

```
@roles.includes(user: :allocations).where({ allocations: { user_id: nil }})

@roles.includes(user: :allocations).group('user.id').having('count(user.allocations) = 0')
```

None of them seems to be working for me.

Comment: What's wrong with first solution? Does it return roles instead of users? If so, just use `pluck` to select desired fields

Comment: ```ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "allocations"```

Comment: I think you may need to user `references` as well to be able to access the allocations table. `@roles.includes(...).references(user: :allocations)...`. I believe without that, it doesn't actually join the table and just merely eager loads the association

Answer (score 2):

I think your first option will work if you use `left_outer_joins`.

`@roles.left_outer_joins(user: :allocations).where({ allocations: { user_id: nil }})`